# Exception has occurred. _TypeError (type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<dynamic>')

Tags: flutter, dart

I am new to flutter, so I honestly don't know the why I am receiving this error.

```
List < BaseResponse > pEShippingDetail = [];
  Future loadMessageList() async {
    http.Response response = await http.get('xxxxx');
    //await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 3));

    String content = response.body;
    List collection = json.decode(content);
    List < BaseResponse > _messages = collection.map((json) => BaseResponse.fromJson(json)).toList();

    setState(() {
      pEShippingDetail = _messages;
    });
  }

  void initState() {
    loadMessageList();
    super.initState();

  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `json.decode(content);` produced a `_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>` but you are try to assign it to a `List` of type `dynamic`(default type).

To solve this, first see what is the data format of the response is. Then use required type. You could use `final` without static type but that's not the best option here. `Map<String, dynamic>` should work but cannot explicitly say it is correct without looking at the json response.

Comment: Can you please show me in an example, because I am still stuck.

Comment: Instead of `List collection = json.decode(content);` use `Iterable collection = json.decode(content);`

Answer (score 1):

That get request is returning a JSON object, not a list. JSON objects are decoded to `Map<String, dynamic>`. So the exception is because you are trying to assign a `Map<String, dynamic>` to a List variable, which cannot be done.

Looking at the response above though, perhaps you mean to use the `categories` property in the response, not the entire response?

Have a closer look at the response, and decide which parts of the data you are actually interested in.